# How can I prevent new-line after all items in enumeration?

Tags: enumerate

I want to prevent added new-line after all items in `enumerate`.

My code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  Start an enumeration:
  \begin{enumerate*}[label=(\arabic*),itemjoin=\\]
    \item[$(i)$] The first item
    \item[$(ii)$] Second item
    \item[$(iii)$] Third item
    \item[$(iv-vi)$] Fourth,fifth, and sixt item.
  \end{enumerate*}
\end{document}
```

generated output, by default all items have new-line at the end:

```
Start an enumeration: (i) The first item
(ii) Second item
(iii) Third item
(iv-vi) Fourth,fifth, and sixt item.
```

wanted output (no new line in between items.):

```
Start an enumeration: (i) The first item (ii) Second item (iii) Third item (iv-vi) Fourth,fifth, and sixt item.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace  `\itemjoin=\\` with `\itemjoin=\quad` (or any horizontal space you please), and everything works fine:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

    \begin{document}

      Start an enumeration:
      \begin{enumerate*}[label=(\arabic*),itemjoin=\quad]
        \item[$(i)$] The first item
        \item[$(ii)$] Second item
        \item[$(iii)$] Third item
        \item[$(iv)$] Third item.
      \end{enumerate*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just added `$(iv-vi)$` right after your answer into my question, here is it also possible to prevent extra space in between number and the dash?

Comment: Use $(iv$-$vi)$ instead

Comment: I was using `\usepackage{enumitem}` as well for other items (without new line) , when I try to use both I am having `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package enumitem.` error :-(

Comment: Could you post a minimal, yet  complete code reproducing this problem?

Comment: Replacing `\usepackage{enumitem}` with `\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}` solved it

Comment: That's fine! :-)

Comment: What could I use only for a space (default spacing) instead of `\quad`? `\enspace` would be ok?

Comment: @Alper: Maybe try  `itemjoin=\ `. If it's not enough, you might try `itemjoin=\enspace`.